# Unable to create PRODUCT_USER_PROFILE synonym

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle12c, hp-ux

```
SQL> conn SYSTEM/psswd123
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
```

I am logged in as a system user but its showing user is "sys"
how to solve this issue.Because of this iam unable to run the `pupbld.sql` file as a sytem user.
I tried to run the `pupbld.sql` script as a system user i am getting error like

> DROP SYNONYM PRODUCT_USER_PROFILE 
>   ERROR at line 1: ORA-01434: private
>   synonym to be dropped does not exist

operating system is hpux

Please help me out in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which database version is it? I tried it on my 11g XE - connection to SYSTEM really connected me as SYSTEM, not SYS. Is there any database on logon trigger which changes *something*?

Comment: Its is in Oracle 12-C enterprise edition.CAN I DROP a SYSTEM user?.Is its cause any problem?

Comment: Nope. SYS and SYSTEM actually "own" the database, I don't know whether they can be dropped. Even if you could do it, it would ruin your database as you'd drop dictionary, metadata ... everything.

Comment: Yeah i know SYS and SYSTEM owned by database ..how to change the owner ship of the "SYSTEM" SYS to SYSTEM.

Comment: It is vice versa. They own the database. I don't think that you can do much about it. In fact, I can't imagine what you might have done wrong so that you have such problems. Did installation went well? Any errors? Basically, you need a good DBA (and I'm not the one).